# Permission Denied error setting 777 folder access

Tags: unix, ubuntu-14.04

I created a user with admin access named hadoop. The funny thing is that when I create a folder and try to give it 777 access it gives me back an error.

```
hadoop@linux:~$ mkdir testfolder
hadoop@linux:~$ ls -ltra testfolder/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 25 hadoop sudo   4096 Jun 14 20:00 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 hadoop hadoop 4096 Jun 14 20:00 .
hadoop@linux:~$ chmod -777 -R
testfolder/ chmod: cannot read directory ‘testfolder/’: Permission denied
```

Why is that when I am the creator of the directory ?

```
hadoop@linux:~$ groups

hadoop root sudo
```

Strangely, using the GUI, I can go in and right click the directory and change the file permissions. Can anyone help me understand what i am not understanding.

Note : I use Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 1):

Your command `chmod -777 -R testfolder/` is the issue here, more specific the `-` as part of the first argument.

Leave it away, just use `chmod 777 -R testfolder/` and all should be fine...

Not exactly sure about the details, but the `-777` should *remove* permissions, thus preventing access at least to the recursive portion of the command. I assume that is *not* what you want to do. Instead you probably want to grant more permissions to the directory. Looks like the command blocks itself. Though that might be by purpose, at least in an indirect manner.

Comment: It's possible that the command `-777` first removes all permissions and that the error occurs after it tries to recurse into it.

Comment: @MrLister Sure, looks like this is the case.

Comment: @arkascha : Yes it worked. Apologies for my lack of knowledge and thanks